# How does Sunder work with Magic Weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, combat-maneuver

Looking at the rules of [Sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Sunder), it states that the weapon's damage is reduced by the item's hardness before being applied to the item, and [Greater Sunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-sunder-combat---final) states that any excess damage is inflicted on the wielder. As such, can someone attempting to **Sunder** activate their Magic Weapon (such as a [flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming) short-sword) to inflict extra damage to a weapon, and get a higher possibility of harming the other creature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though according to the rules for damaging objects any energy damage is reduced by half before applying to hardness/hp. I don't think there are any specific rules for the order you're required to apply damage in, that would be something to ask your gm.